# ROS Answers SE migration: URDF Guide

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users,
please, give me a hint, where I could find some guide to United Robot Description Format (UDRF)?
Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9810/urdf-guide/) by [ASMIK2011ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/352/asmik2011ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2011-04-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-04-25**:
I was half-way working on a "real-life" example, but never finished, maybe this is motivation to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best place to start is probably [the URDF tutorials list](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials)

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2011-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8